# How to get records of a specific month in SQL

Tags: presto

How do I get the month from current date in presto SQL?

I have a code below but it throws an error..

```
select month(current_date())
from table a
limit 1;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_date` should be used without braces (per SQL standard)

```
presto> SELECT month(current_date);
 _col0
-------
     3
```

Comment: I created https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/3079 to get the docs fixed.